# Problemas con Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner

Tengo un Spinner con un adapter personalizado. Al dar sobre un número no me responde el setOnItemSelectedListener, creo que el problema es el focus que va a mi adapter personalizado y no se como desactivar eso, si alguien me ayuda por favoor.. Aqui mi codigo:

```
private Spinner spMonto
spMonto = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.SpMonto);
List<Integer> montos = new ArrayList<>();//cargar de la base de datos
  montos.add(100000);
    montos.add(200000);
    montos.add(300000);
    montos.add(400000);
    montos.add(500000);
    montos.add(600000);
    montos.add(700000);
    montos.add(800000);
    montos.add(900000);
    montos.add(1000000);
adaptadorS = new AdaptadorTextViewSimple(montos,C);
    spMonto.setAdapter(adaptadorS);
spMonto.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
            montoSelec = Integer.parseInt(textView.getTag().toString());
            Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"montoX "+montoSelec);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Aqui mi adapter (AdaptadorTextViewSimple):

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)C.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (view==null){
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view_simple,null);
    }
    TextView texto = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    texto.setFocusable(false);

    texto.setText(String.valueOf(formatomil.format(integerList.get(i).intValue())));
    texto.setTag(integerList.get(i).intValue());
    return view;
}
```

mi XML del adapter personalizado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="false"    >
<TextView
    android:focusable="false"

    android:id="@+id/txtText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="@color/Negro"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: al seleccionar una opción no responde el llamado al método onItemSelected() ?

Comment: Llama a tal método buscándole lado, creo que hay alguna view que capta el facus del spinner y hace que pierda el focus, el adaptador solo tiene un textview.

Answer (score 0):

el problema era esta linea:

```
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

simplemente lo borré y funcionó!